# How to jQuery UI Tab "OnCilck" goes to another URL?

Tags: jquery-ui, onclick, jquery-ui-tabs, redirect

Lets say i have 10 Tabs. And one of these tabs will link to external URL. How to do it please?

I prefer to make it perform like a normal HREF action. Because when i use:

```
onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com';"
```

or

```
$("#tab-08").click(function(){ ........... });
```

.. there definitely is a DELAY about 1 or 2 seconds, upon the click of that particular Tab.

So how do i override a jQuery UI TAB back to normal  link please?

Answer (score 1):

Some more code would be useful but how about something like this?

Javascript:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true,
    beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
        window.open($(ui.newTab).find('a').attr('href'), '_blank');
        return false;
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Page</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Your solution also works, but I think you are dealing with a browser related problem that is causing the delay.

Comment: But your approach will apply the redirect on every UI Tabs. Am i right? As i said, i want only 1 tab (for example) to act like a real HREF link. All the rests are just the normal UI Tabs. Which means, for the rest of normal Tabs like `<li><a href="#tab-2">Comments</a></li>` .. will still need to be remained as like UI Tabs. (Not going out to another page/site)

Comment: Add some data attribute on anchor tag to identify that you need to do redirect